# How to get the text from a tag that has another tag in it with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How do i get the number '1' which is in the label tag

```html
<label class="btn btn-primary active"><input type="radio"  name="ow_adults"/>1</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just select your label as you want, by id, class, whatever, like...

```js
var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
// suppose your label is at the first position, just get its innerText
var text = labels[0].innerText;

text == 1; // true
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use getElementsByTagName("label")[0].innerHTML you will get all the content.
what you can do is by creating a new attribute you can call it whatever you want like

```
alfa="1"
```

your code will be like that :

```
<label alfa="1" class="btn btn-primary active"><input type="radio"  name="ow_adults"/>1</label>
```

then you can get the content of alfa by this javascript code:

```
<script>
var x = getElementsByTagName("label")[0].getAttribute("alfa") ; 
</script>
```

the code shows 1 
reply if you need anything else .